# z-index of 9999 not working on absolute div

Tags: css, z-index, absolute

The `z-index` on `.mainContentRightForm` is not working. It should be floating above the orange bar, but it sitting behind it. I just can't figure out why, could use some expertise.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.content-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1040px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 38px 50px 50px;
  position: relative;
}


/* landing page masthead */

#mastheadBar {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #FDA929;
}

#mastheadImage {
  max-width: 1520px;
  background-image: url(#);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  margin: auto;
}

.logoWrapper {
  max-width: 310px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #FFF;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table;
}

.LogoWrapperText {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 21px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 54px;
  color: #FFF;
  max-width: 745px;
  margin-top: -14px;
  margin-bottom: 23px;
}


/* landing page main content */

#mainContent {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mainContent p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #737373;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

#mainContent li {
  color: #737373;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin: 0 0 8px 10px;
}

#mainContent ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: disc;
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

#mainContentLeft {
  float: left;
  width: 57.4468085106383%;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

#mainContentLeftWrap {
  margin-bottom: 11px;
}

#mainContentRightForm {
  background: white;
  padding: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 340px;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: thin solid #F00;
  right: 50px;
  top: -154px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="mastheadBar">
    <div id="mastheadImage">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="logoWrapper">
          <div class="LogoWrapperText">${logo-text}</div>
        </div>
        <h1>${page-title}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mainContent">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div id="mainContentLeft">
        <div id="mainContentLeftWrap" class="mktoText" mktoName="Main Body 
    Text">
          <p>Aenean sed orci efficitur, convallis arcu sit amet, consequat dolor. Vestibulum vestibulum nisl quis mattis rhoncus. Cras ut imperdiet leo. Phasellus luctus mauris lectus, quis semper dui dignissim at. Donec lacinia, turpis ac hendrerit dictum,
            erat nisl iaculis lacus, eu ultrices libero nisi eu sapien. Praesent id congue elit, sed rutrum lorem. Duis quis nisi elit. Pellentesque nec cursus leo.</p>
          <p>Vivamus quis ex pellentesque, pharetra elit eget, molestie arcu:</p>
          <ul>
            <li>Integer ornare velit metus, sit amet tincidunt neque</li>
            <li>luctus vitae. Suspendisse vulputate cursus</li>
            <li>scelerisque. Sed ac lectus eget nisi facilisis</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mainContentRightForm">Please fill in the form below.Aenean sed orci efficitur, convallis arcu sit amet, consequat dolor. Vestibulum vestibulum nisl quis mattis rhoncus. Cras ut imperdiet leo. Phasellus luctus mauris lectus, quis semper dui dignissim at. Donec lacinia,
        turpis ac hendrerit dictum, erat nisl iaculis lacus, eu ultrices libero nisi eu sapien. Praesent id congue elit, sed rutrum lorem. Duis quis nisi elit. Pellentesque nec cursus leo.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `z-index` on a child element (`#mainContentRightForm`) won't layer it on top of its parents (`#mainContent`) sibling (`#mastheadBar`), for that to work the `#mainContent` need a `z-index`.

In this case, you don't need a `z-index` as it is the `overflow: hidden` on `.content-wrapper` and `#mainContent` that prevents the `#mainContentRightForm` to display uncut.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.content-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1040px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 38px 50px 50px;
  position: relative;
}


/* landing page masthead */

#mastheadBar {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #FDA929;
}

#mastheadImage {
  max-width: 1520px;
  background-image: url(#);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  margin: auto;
}

.logoWrapper {
  max-width: 310px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #FFF;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table;
}

.LogoWrapperText {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 21px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 54px;
  color: #FFF;
  max-width: 745px;
  margin-top: -14px;
  margin-bottom: 23px;
}


/* landing page main content */

#mainContent {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mainContent p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #737373;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

#mainContent li {
  color: #737373;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin: 0 0 8px 10px;
}

#mainContent ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: disc;
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

#mainContentLeft {
  float: left;
  width: 57.4468085106383%;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

#mainContentLeftWrap {
  margin-bottom: 11px;
}

#mainContentRightForm {
  background: white;
  padding: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 340px;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: thin solid #F00;
  right: 50px;
  top: -154px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="mastheadBar">
    <div id="mastheadImage">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="logoWrapper">
          <div class="LogoWrapperText">${logo-text}</div>
        </div>
        <h1>${page-title}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mainContent">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div id="mainContentLeft">
        <div id="mainContentLeftWrap" class="mktoText" mktoName="Main Body 
    Text">
          <p>Aenean sed orci efficitur, convallis arcu sit amet, consequat dolor. Vestibulum vestibulum nisl quis mattis rhoncus. Cras ut imperdiet leo. Phasellus luctus mauris lectus, quis semper dui dignissim at. Donec lacinia, turpis ac hendrerit dictum,
            erat nisl iaculis lacus, eu ultrices libero nisi eu sapien. Praesent id congue elit, sed rutrum lorem. Duis quis nisi elit. Pellentesque nec cursus leo.</p>
          <p>Vivamus quis ex pellentesque, pharetra elit eget, molestie arcu:</p>
          <ul>
            <li>Integer ornare velit metus, sit amet tincidunt neque</li>
            <li>luctus vitae. Suspendisse vulputate cursus</li>
            <li>scelerisque. Sed ac lectus eget nisi facilisis</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mainContentRightForm">Please fill in the form below.Aenean sed orci efficitur, convallis arcu sit amet, consequat dolor. Vestibulum vestibulum nisl quis mattis rhoncus. Cras ut imperdiet leo. Phasellus luctus mauris lectus, quis semper dui dignissim at. Donec lacinia,
        turpis ac hendrerit dictum, erat nisl iaculis lacus, eu ultrices libero nisi eu sapien. Praesent id congue elit, sed rutrum lorem. Duis quis nisi elit. Pellentesque nec cursus leo.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```